# Prime ideals of Diamond Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, semisimple-lie-algebras

The real Diamond Lie algebra $\mathfrak{D}$ is a four-dimensional Lie algebra with basis $\left\{ J, P_{1}, P_{2}, T \right\}$ and non-zero relations
$$
\left[J, P_{1}\right]=P_{2}, \quad\left[J, P_{2}\right]=-P_{1}, \quad\left[P_{1}, P_{2}\right]=T
$$
The complexification of the Diamond Lie algebra: $\mathfrak{D} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathrm{C}$ displays the following complex basis:
$$
\left\{P_{+}=P_{1}-i P_{2}, \quad P_{-}=P_{1}+i P_{2}, \quad T, \quad J\right\}
$$
where $i$ is the imaginary unit, whose nonzero commutators are
$$
\left[J, P_{+}\right]=i P_{+}, \quad\left[J, P_{-}\right]=-i P_{-}, \quad\left[P_{+}, P_{-}\right]=2 i T
$$

**An ideal $P$ of Lie algebra $L$ is called prime if $[H, K] \subseteq P$ with $H, K$ ideals of $L$ implies $H \subseteq P$ or $K \subseteq P$**

> How can I determine the ideals and compute the relations between ideals to know the prime ideals in $\mathfrak{D}$?

> Are there a way to determine the ideals (In general in any Lie algebra not specifically $\mathfrak{D}$) or compute its relation by using the commutators of the basis as given above ?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg

Comment: For a finite-dimensional Lie algebra $A$ in char. zero and ideal $I$, $A/I$ is prime (in your definition) iff $A/I$ is semisimple (easy exercise), or equivalently if $I$ contains the solvable radical. So when $A$ is solvable, $I$ is prime iff $I=A$.

Comment: If you want to determine the ideals of a given $A$, a workable method is the following: determine the minimal nonzero ideals, and then classify the ideals of the quotients by those minimal nonzero ideals (which are smaller-dimensional). In this precise case this is easy to perform.

Comment: Does this Diamond Lie algebra D is solvable ?

Comment: Could you give me an example for your method please ?